# replace a content with another using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using one of the bootstrap snippet for [login dropdown box](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/33ZWp) in the login box there is a link for `Join Us` I wanted that when i click on Join Us, the content within the box should get replaced by another box that contains login credentials

I modified the following code

```
New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
```

with the code below

```
New here ? <a href="#" onClick="$('#login-dp').hide(); $('#signup-dp').show()"><b>Join Us</b></a>
```

and created another content that had id `signup-dp` like this

```
<ul id="signup-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
// signup data Inside this part
</ul>
```

Now when i click on the Join Us link the url of the page gets changed i.e #signup in the end of the url, but the content does not get displayed,
can anyone please tell how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please check jquery included or not.
>
> Use `return false` like below

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('#login-dp').hide(); $('#signup-dp').show(); return false;"><b>Join Us</b></a>
```

```css
#signup-dp{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onClick="$('#login-dp').hide(); $('#signup-dp').show(); return false;"><b>Join Us</b></a>
<div id="login-dp">login-dp</div>
<div id="signup-dp">signup-dp</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple and you code is working for me only.

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('#login-dp').hide(); $('#signup-dp').show()">    
    <b>Join Us</b>
</a>
<a href="#" onClick="$('#login-dp').show(); $('#signup-dp').hide()">
    <b>Login</b>
</a>
<ul id="signup-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
    // signup data Inside this part
</ul>
<ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
    // login data Inside this part
</ul>
```

Please follow this link . [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16r1Lwsh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. But please check have you included jquery file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This jquery should be included before the jquery code you have written.

Put following jquery code to make signup div initially hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#signup-dp").hide();
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Onclick jQuery is not working, So user Javascript code

```
New here ? <a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("login-dp").style.display = "none";document.getElementById("signup-dp").style.display = "visible";'><b>Join Us</b></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the new hidden element somewhere before your existing  element.
unless you write your jQuery code in `$(document).ready();` in a separate file, or internal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for make good programming habit you have to bind click event instead of write javascript code inside of tag onClick attribute.

```
<a href="#" id="btn_join_us"><b>Join Us</b></a>
```

In your javascript code (try to write code in other js file instead of inline code in HTML page.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_join_us").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#login-dp').hide(); 
        $('#signup-dp').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

This kind of code make some secure event binding. otherwise anyone can make change your code from inspect element and execute this.

Comment: thanks for the tip regarding security, will surely keep that in mind